# Were Russian female spies caught, because they exclaimed in Russian during child birth?

Tags: espionage

Actor Costa Ronin contends this, but didn't mention any names or evidence.

https://youtu.be/PHcafz2Aon8?t=2323

Comment: The skeptic in me doubts that multiple Russian spies were 'caught' simply by exclaiming in Russian in a moment of stress. Not everyone who speaks Russian is a spy, so speaking Russian wouldn't be proof all by itself. If this happened at all, I would think that the spy was already under investigation and their exclamations were simply one more piece of evidence against them.

Comment: Yes, if you count fictional spies.

Comment: The legend is based on a very popular Russian TV series of 1970s "17 moments of spring", where such episode is shown (during WWII). The movie plot is 100% fiction.

Comment: @KillingTime  OTOH, there are situations where speaking Russian would be enough to generate suspicion.  (Especially if this is a surprise, leading to the conclusion that the person willfully hid it.)

Comment: Not a notable claim.

Comment: Why would a spy get pregnant, and carry to term?

Comment: Incidentally, the fictional name of the fictional spy was Katherin Kinn, and see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seventeen_Moments_of_Spring). As for "why would she carry to term": It was required by the book/movie plot and also, abortion in Nazi Germany by 1943 was illegal. Incidentally, in USSR it was illegal between 1936 and 1955; afterwards, it was legal but discouraged. Thus, for a Soviet spy to have an abortion would be somewhere between impossible to politically incorrect.

Comment: @jamesqf A family is less suspicious so why not?

Answer (score 2):

As @Alex has correctly pointed out, this story is based on the 1970s megahit fictional series "17 Moments of Spring" about a high-level Russian spy at the heart of the Nazi intelligence and repression machine.

But that plot is far from 100% fictional and, in fact, and one would do well to remember that [Yulian Semyonov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yulian_Semyonov) who wrote the novel on which the series is based was something of an unofficial poet-laureate of the Soviet foreign espionage service and had access to a lot of true material which he used in his work. Many of the details and subplots he wrote about are known to be based on reality.

So, on the premise that Semyonov has perhaps worked a story he had from his sources into the plot, I googled around a bit in Russian and came up with a few leads. They are not entirely conclusive but still.

1. [Lyudmila Nuikina](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyudmila_Nuikina) and her husband Vitaly worked undercover in 18 countries as Soviet spies. She gave birth to her second child during one of her assignments and in recent interviews she presents two different versions of what happened:

(a) She took care to scream in French (which according to her cover story was her mother tongue).

From her 21/02/2020 [interview](https://www.mk.ru/social/2020/02/21/russkaya-razvedchicanelegal-opisala-rody-za-granicey.html):

> — Вы рожали за границей. Был риск, что могли во время родов закричать
> по-русски? Помните эпизод из тех же «Семнадцати мгновений весны», где
> Штирлиц говорит радистке Кэт: «Ты будешь кричать «мамочка»
> по-рязански»?
>
> - Рожала я за границей второго ребенка. Кричала по-французски. Я в командировках сделала русский язык врагом номер один. Мы с мужем
>   никогда не говорили на нем на чужбине. Даже ссорились исключительно на
>   иностранном.

In a [slightly earlier interview from 2018](https://rg.ru/2018/12/20/razvedchica-liudmila-nujkina-my-poiavliaemsia-kak-by-iz-vozduha.html) she gives the same account.

(b) However, in [yet another interview](http://mospravda.ru/2020/10/30/169712/) from from 30/10/2020 she says that she gave birth in silence, using her own credentials as a former midwife (yes, she is a woman of many accomplishments indeed) to slightly ridicule the whole notion:

> – А как же знаменитая история из «Семнадцати мгновений весны», что
> рожающие женщины кричат слово «мама» на родном языке?
>
> – Никогда не понимала, зачем кричать при родах. Может, оттого, что
> сама столько родов приняла… Я оба раза рожала молча.

The exact truth of the matter in her case will probably not be revealed but she does seem to have had the issue in mind and to have been bothered about it.

2. Two more similar cases are mentioned in [this article](https://zen.yandex.ru/media/russian7/krichala-ponemecki-kak-rojali-sovetskie-razvedchicy-5f1e7adc082c3d64be386232). In one, the agent screamed in German and in the other in an unspecified foreign language.

To sum up, it's hard to disentangle fact from fiction from life imitating art in this case but there does seem to be something out there.